# 301 redirect adding param to URL after rewriting URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite

I am rewriting my URLs like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?page/([a-z0-9\-]*)/ /page.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Now I changed an URL and want to redirect it with 301:

```
Redirect 301 /page/example-old/ /page/example-new/
```

The problem: It adds the URL param. Result is:

```
/page/example-new/?url=example-new
```

What am I doing wrong? I want the redirect without the added URL param.

Comment: could you please do mention samples of urls eg: FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect AND in backend what query strings/parameters you want to send? That will give clear picture of your question, thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I mentioned to example above. For example I want to redirect from "/page/old-entry/" to "/page/new-entry/". The result is "/page/new-entry/?url=new-entry".

No idea why it behaves like this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using mod_rewrite already, it is usually best to implement redirecws with mod_rewrite as well:

```sh
RewriteRule ^/?page/example-old/ /page/example-new/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?page/([a-z0-9\-]*)/ /page.php?url=$1 [L]
```

That way the first rule prevents the second rule from running because the first rule uses the `L` (last) flag.